# как реализовать таймер в боте вк

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Мне надо реализовать временный бан. Работаю с MySQL. Выполнение кода происходит после нового события из LongPoll

```
import vk_api
import pymysql.cursors
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '12345678'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    #Вот здесь надо что то придумать
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте таблицу с полями **| id | time_end |**

Когда кто-то получает временный бан, например на час, то добавляете id этого пользователя в базу вместе со временем окончания бана в unixtime.

Если бот запускается на linux, то вы можете использовать утилиту crontab для ежеминутной проверки. Создаете скрипт, который вытягивает всех забаненых пользователей? проходитесь по ним и проверяете, если текущее время больше, чем в БД, то удаляете пользователя из забаненных. Ставите этот скрипт на выполнение в cron каждую минуту.

Если на windows, то погуглите другие планировщики заданий

Comment: Примерно так я себе и представлял, но вы помогли мне представить это лучше.